# PDF button to submit input to paypal

Tags: pdf, paypal

I am trying to setup online registration for our car show.  I have an interactive PDF that totals up the final cost.  I want the submit button to take that total number, add 3% (for the paypal fee) and send that to paypal as well as email the completed PDF to an email address.  First, is this all possible?  I've been beating my head with the submit button to send it to paypal, I keep getting Syntax errors.  Code I am trying to use in the submit button of the PDF is:

```
var totalcost = this.getField("Total").value;
var paypaltotal = totalcost + (totalcost * 3%);
app.launchURL("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=enemetz@gmail.com&item_name="TA Nationals"&amount=paypaltotal&currency_code=USD&bn=PP%2dBuyNowBF&charset=UTF");
```

Comment: What output are you seeing in the Acrobat JavaScript console?

Comment: only states: "SyntaxError: syntax error
2:"

Comment: *"totalcost * 3%"* - are you sure JavaScript supports percentiles calculation like that?

Comment: I should have noticed that. I'm surprised Acrobat let you put that code in the button at all. It's syntactically incorrect on line 2.

Comment: Hmm... it's never thrown an error on it, so I thought it would work.. so it should be * .03 then ?  Or is there a better way to calculate it?  But still not sure why the link errors.. as if I copy between the quotes (and change the paypaltotal to a number) the link works.

Comment: Ok, changed it to * .03  and the SyntaxError syntax error 2 on line 3 goes away.. but it now states SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list 3 at line 4.